# Is it possible to create objects of class type within the class in php

Tags: php, class, oop, object, php-7

I need something like this for my school project.

```
class Node {
  Node $obj;   
}
```

How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: Do you mean defining a type property, or just using an instance of the class' own type inside it?

Comment: Using an instance of the class' own type inside it.

Comment: @MetinKadık I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. But you can type the parameters of a method and the return type :

```
class Node {
    private $obj = null;
    public function setNode(Node $obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }
    public function getNode():Node {
        return $this->obj;
    }
}
```

Note that if `$obj` is `null` you will have an error if you use `getNode()`. So you could use `:?Node` to allow null return.

```
    public function getNode():?Node { // OK if $this->obj is NULL
        return $this->obj;
    }
```

---

**EDIT**

To use an instance of the current object, you could use `$this` :

```
class Node {
    public $obj = null;
    public function createInstance() {
        $this->obj = $this;
    }
}

$node = new Node();
$node->createInstance();

var_dump($node);
var_dump($node->obj);
```

Will outputs :

```
object(Node)#1 (1) {
  ["obj"]=>
  *RECURSION*
}
object(Node)#1 (1) {
  ["obj"]=>
  *RECURSION*
}
```

As you can see `$node` and `$node->obj` are the same object (`object(Node)#1`).